# What's the word for when someone selectively chooses the statements said to them to take and use deceitfully?

Tags: single-word-requests

It’s when someone selectively chooses the statements said to them to take and use deceitfully.

Example:

- Person A: You do so and so all the time and it’s annoying!
- Person B: I don’t do it *all* the time

What I’m trying to describe is what Person B did. It's similar to discarded  *pedantic*, *paltering*, and *pettifogging* but it's not quite those.

I really need to find this word.

Comment: You listed some possible synonyms in your question. Why don't those words work?

Comment: Are you talking about distortion?

Comment: flippancy, "being facetious"

Comment: Theres a specific word im looking for but I cant seem to remember what it is. It isnt any of the synonyms I listed.

Comment: Split hairs or nitpick?  I propose these because you liked *quibble.*

Comment: As someone who finds it unhelpful and confusing when people exaggerate while trying to criticise me, I called it "being accurate".

Comment: @Matt Yes, OP's example could no doubt  be improved upon. 'You do so and so all the time ...!' is doubtless hyperbole. It would be better to have Person A make a statement that can't reasonably _invite_ criticism.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 1):

The overall behaviour is **captious**

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/captious)
> *captious*
> 1 marked by an often ill-natured inclination to stress faults and raise objections
> 2 calculated to confuse, entrap, or entangle in argument

In more detail, person B is cavilling, carping or quibbling.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cavil)
> *cavil*
> to raise trivial and frivolous objection

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/carp)
> *carp*
> to complain about unimportant matters

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quibble)
> *Quibble*:
> to argue or complain about small and unimportant details

They cavil, carp or quibble by focussing on part of the argument. They are being **picky**.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/picky)
> *picky*:
> Someone who is picky is very careful about choosing only what they like
> Example:
> *That should not be done in narrow terms, or with a picky, legalistic approach to language.*

Comment: Someone disagreed with this answer. Merely for the sake of the questioner, I wonder if they would be kind enough to explain why? Or are  they just carping to themselves?

Comment: Quibble has a very close definition to the word im looking for.

Comment: It is a reasonable general question based on a specific example. I see no reason to downvote it so have compensated.

Comment: The question refers to selective quotation and deceit, while the answers are all much more general and convey neither selective quotation nor deceitfulness, and could refer to behaviour which is playful or overly legalistic without (in most cases) the element of dishonesty or the precise behaviour described.

Comment: @StuartF The question does not refer to deceit in the sense of concealing the truth. It refers to some extent to sophistry, a great deal to flawed logic, and to selective argument. Although reprehensible, none of these are concealment. The partial relevance of deceit may be that all these are distortions of the truth, but "deceit" is not the relevant overarching concept.